# Why do we cast a object in order to compare after checking with instanceof?

Tags: java

Here is the code from an online tutorial i follow:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private int height;

    // constructors and methods


    public boolean equals(Object compared) {
        // if the variables are located in the same position, they are equal
        if (this == compared) {
            return true;
        }

        // if the compared object is not of type Person, the objects are not equal
        if (!(compared instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }

        // convert the object into a Person object
        Person comparedPerson = (Person) compared;

        // if the values of the object variables are equal, the objects are equal
        if (this.name.equals(comparedPerson.name) &&
            this.age == comparedPerson.age &&
            this.weight == comparedPerson.weight &&
            this.height == comparedPerson.height) {
            return true;
        }

        // otherwise the objects are not equal
        return false;
    }

    // .. methods
}
```

Why and how we cast `compared` after already checking it with instanceof. If it is not an instance of `Person` method will return false and thus no need to cast. If ıt is an instance of `Person`, no need to cast because it already is.

Comment: You need to cast it to access its properties for further comparison.

Comment: Seems you'll be interested in [JEP 305: Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305)

Comment: @Kayaman my point is why is that? it is already a object, so can't i just put a dot and write the attributes or methods.

Comment: @AliA Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @Turing85 the link you provided seems like i could make use of it but i am a beginner in OOP and Java so terms used there were too implicit for me. Would you like to eleborate what they said by answering this question?

Comment: _The object_ is a `Person`, but _the type of the variable_ (or, more exactly, the expression) before casting is merely `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the fields that are defined in `Person` in the `if` down two lines.

```
if (this.name.equals(comparedPerson.name) &&
    this.age == comparedPerson.age &&
    this.weight == comparedPerson.weight &&
    this.height == comparedPerson.height) {
    return true;
}
```

`Object` does not have `name`, `age`, `weight` or `height`.

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to access the fields which are specific to the `Person` class without casting.

```
Person comparedPerson = (Person) compared;
```